# How to start system shutdown or poweroff by hardware interrupt

Tags: embedded, shutdown, gpio

I have a small headless embedded Linux box (NXP i.MX6, with userspace based on Debian, but am interested in more general solution).

It has no HID input, no desktop stuff, just a serial console and a GPIO interrupt (a button) which I want to initiate power-off. Like the ACPI button on machines which have it.

All promising looking stuff in  linux/drivers/power/reset (POWER_RESET_GPIO, POWER_RESET_IMX...) is actually not helpful - all these are low lever drivers which   do the physical shut down or restart.

The missing link is how to handle the GPIO interrupt so that it causes system shut down, similar to the "poweroff" command.

Googled, but to much surprise, cannot find anything ready.

Suppose I can get the interrupt into userspace by something like [uio driver](https://yurovsky.github.io/2014/10/10/linux-uio-gpio-interrupt.html) and execute 'poweroff'? Is it the only option? I think this is a common need and there should be a common solution?